# Unexpected else?

Tags: php, syntax-error

I tried this same coding in several ways, and none of them work.

```
public function getCalendarById($calendarId)
{
    $calendarsList = $this->getCalendarsList();
    if($calendarId == "1") {
        return $this->getMergedCalendars();
    } else {
        return (array_key_exists($calendarId, $calendarsList) ? $calendarsList[$calendarId] : null);
    } else {//******** error here ***********
        return (array_key_exists($calendarId, $calendarsList) ? $this->holidayrize($calendarId) : null);
    }
}
```

The error happens in the commented line. It says Unexpected T_ELSE

Any ideas why?

Comment: Probably the first `else` is intended as `else if`

Comment: if (condition) ... else if (another condition) ... else

Comment: You need `elseif` and a condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the syntax is wrong. You can't have multiple `else` clauses in a single `if` statement.

You can use `elseif` instead:

```
if($calendarId == "1") {
    return $this->getMergedCalendars();
} elseif ( /* second condition here */ ) {
    return (array_key_exists($calendarId, $calendarsList) ? $calendarsList[$calendarId] : null);
} else {
    return (array_key_exists($calendarId, $calendarsList) ? $this->holidayrize($calendarId) : null);
}
```

or a `switch` statement, if you're expecting more options.

Answer (score 6):

You have two else blocks. That makes no sense and is thus not allowed.

You need to remove one of them, merge the contents of both (doesn't make sense though since only one `return` can be executed anyway) or turn the first one into an `elseif(some condition)` block.

With an `elseif` it would look like this; you just need to insert a condition to make it work:

```
public function getCalendarById($calendarId)
{
    $calendarsList = $this->getCalendarsList();
    if($calendarId == "1") {
        return $this->getMergedCalendars();
    }
    elseif(/*put some condition here*/) {
        return (array_key_exists($calendarId, $calendarsList) ? $calendarsList[$calendarId] : null);
    }
    else {
        return (array_key_exists($calendarId, $calendarsList) ? $this->holidayrize($calendarId) : null);
    }
}
```